# filter array of data multiple values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this question has been asked before, but existing solutions do not seem to work for my case. I am trying to filter out data on the basis of multiple properties/values in a varied array of objects.

My sample data looks like this:

```
const products = [
          { name: 'A', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'USA' },
          { name: 'B', color: 'Blue', size: 60, locations: 'Europe' },
          { name: 'C', color: 'Blue', size: 30, locations: 'Europe' },
          { name: 'D', color: 'Black', size: 70, locations: 'Japan' },
          { name: 'E', color: 'Green', size: 50, locations: 'Europe' },
          { name: 'F', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'Brazil' },
          { name: 'G', color: 'Black', size: 40, locations: 'Australia' },
        ];
```

This is what I require the filters result to be:

```
const filters_one = ['Blue'];

const requiredResult_One = [
      { name: 'A', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'USA' }, 
      { name: 'B', color: 'Blue', size: 60, locations: 'Europe' },
      { name: 'C', color: 'Blue', size: 30, locations: 'Europe' },
      { name: 'E', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'Brazil' }, 
]


const filters_two = ['Blue', 'Europe'];

const requiredResult_Two = [
      { name: 'B', color: 'Blue', size: 60, locations: 'Europe' },
      { name: 'C', color: 'Blue', size: 30, locations: 'Europe' }, 
]


----------OR-------------------------
const filters_three = ['Black'];

const requiredResult_three = [
      { name: 'D', color: 'Black', size: 70, locations: 'Japan' },
      { name: 'G', color: 'Black', size: 40, locations: 'Australia' }, 
]

const filters_four = ['Black', 'Japan'];

const requiredResult_Four = [
      { name: 'D', color: 'Black', size: 70, locations: 'Japan' },
]
```

this is what I have achieved so far:

```
const filterdata = (products, filter) => {
      // where, filter can be equal to *filters_one*, *filters_two*, *filters_three*, 
         or *filters_four* anyone of it. //

      const keysExact = ['color', 'locations'];
      const valuesExact = filter.map(col => col.toLowerCase());

      const resultExact = products.filter((prod) =>
          keysExact.every((key) => valuesExact.includes(prod[key].toLowerCase()))
      );

      console.log(resultExact);
};
```

This seems to work partially or not looks like a good approach to me. If anyone can help me with a way better solution on this, will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the values from the object and check if all values of the query is in the values array.

```js
const
    filter = (data, query) => data.filter(o => {
        const values = Object.values(o);
        return query.every(q => values.includes(q));
    }),
    products = [{ name: 'A', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'USA' }, { name: 'B', color: 'Blue', size: 60, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'C', color: 'Blue', size: 30, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'D', color: 'Black', size: 70, locations: 'Japan' }, { name: 'E', color: 'Green', size: 50, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'F', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'Brazil' }, { name: 'G', color: 'Black', size: 40, locations: 'Australia' }];

console.log(filter(products, ['Blue']));
console.log(filter(products, ['Blue', 'Europe']));
console.log(filter(products, ['Black']));
console.log(filter(products, ['Black', 'Japan']));
console.log(filter(products, [['Blue', 'Green']]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach for alternate values of the same key.

```js
const
    filter = (data, query) => data.filter(o => {
        const values = Object.values(o);
        return query.every(q =>
            values.includes(q) ||
            Array.isArray(q) && q.some(v => values.includes(v))
        );
    }),
    products = [{ name: 'A', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'USA' }, { name: 'B', color: 'Blue', size: 60, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'C', color: 'Blue', size: 30, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'D', color: 'Black', size: 70, locations: 'Japan' }, { name: 'E', color: 'Green', size: 50, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'F', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'Brazil' }, { name: 'G', color: 'Black', size: 40, locations: 'Australia' }];

console.log(filter(products, ['Blue']));
console.log(filter(products, [['Blue', 'Green']]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice and clean! But can you explain please the comma at the end of line 5.

Comment: do you mean after `})`? if so, it separates the `const` declarations and initializations.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the clean solution. Can you please help with something more? If I filter only on the basis of two or more colors only, like ['Blue', 'Green'], it should return data that belongs from these two colors but it does not give any result. Can you please help tweak this solution a bit?

Comment: actually **all** values are required for the filtering. if you want an alternate value for the same key, you could use an array for it and check with `Array#some`.

Comment: @NinaScholz So with this new approach, data can be filtered on the basis of any values combination? I mean, any combination of color and location OR color or location?

Comment: sorry, it is not possible to search for either one item or for every items with the same filtering function.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting this know. Can you give some hint on how I can achieve in different functions ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const filterArray = (filter, arr) => {
   return arr.filter(val => (filter[1] 
                       ? val.color === filter[0] && val.locations === filter[1] 
                       : val.color === filter[0]));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter based on `color` and `location`

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'A', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'USA' },
  { name: 'B', color: 'Blue', size: 60, locations: 'Europe' },
  { name: 'C', color: 'Blue', size: 30, locations: 'Europe' },
  { name: 'D', color: 'Black', size: 70, locations: 'Japan' },
  { name: 'E', color: 'Green', size: 50, locations: 'Europe' },
  { name: 'F', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'Brazil' },
  { name: 'G', color: 'Black', size: 40, locations: 'Australia' },
];

function filterProducts(filterParams) {
  const [color, country] = filterParams;
  const output = products.filter((product) => product.color === color && (country ? product.locations  === country : true))
  return output;
}
const filters_one = ['Blue'];
const requiredResult_One = filterProducts(filters_one);
console.log(requiredResult_One);


const filters_two = ['Blue', 'Europe'];
const requiredResult_Two = filterProducts(filters_two);
console.log(requiredResult_Two);


const filters_three = ['Black'];
const requiredResult_three = filterProducts(filters_three);
console.log(requiredResult_three);

const filters_four = ['Black', 'Japan'];
const requiredResult_Four = filterProducts(filters_four);
console.log(requiredResult_Four);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to filter list:

```js
let products = [{ name: 'A', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'USA' }, { name: 'B', color: 'Blue', size: 60, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'C', color: 'Blue', size: 30, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'D', color: 'Black', size: 70, locations: 'Japan' }, { name: 'E', color: 'Green', size: 50, locations: 'Europe' }, { name: 'F', color: 'Blue', size: 50, locations: 'Brazil' }, { name: 'G', color: 'Black', size: 40, locations: 'Australia' },];
function* filter(array, list = {}) {
    loop: for (let item of array) {
        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(list))
            if (item[k] != v)
                continue loop;

        yield item;
    }
}
console.log("size:50", [...filter(products, { size: 50 })])
console.log("color:Blue", [...filter(products, { color: 'Blue' })])
console.log("color:Blue, size:50", [...filter(products, { color: 'Blue', size: 50 })])
console.log("color:Blue, locations:Europe", [...filter(products, { color: 'Blue', locations: 'Europe' })])
```

This example is very fast, flexible and lazy!